# best approach on building react base layout with css grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to build react app with multiple components like Instagram for example.
coming from HTML/CSS/JS - each page had his own design and layout.
now react doesnt change page, it just renders different component be it a login page, profile page, feed and etc.
Now i was wondering how to implement css grid in react app that contains multiple complex components.
Should i make a grid layout on the App.js that holds all the main components like the register, login, feed & etc
or should i create a grid for each component that i use as a "page" (register, login, feed & etc) & just ignore the App.js style?

EDIT -
each component will have a different look
for example register page will have a registration form
login page will have a different looking form and design
feed is a component that will show header and that user's images as gallery.
search will show all the users profiles as gallery.

[image: example]

so im asking if i should just put some basic resets in the body {}
and style each component as if it was a page by itself **or** should i build some main layout like  in App.js (App.scss will hold the style itself)?

```
function App() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getMe() {
            try {
                const user = await UserService.me();
                if (!user) {
                    history.push('/login');
                    return;
                }
                setUser(user);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        getMe();
    }, [history]);

    function isLoggedIn() {
        return Boolean(Object.keys(user).length);
    }

  return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <div className="App">
            <div className="main">
              <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/register">
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/login">
                        <Login />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/post/create">
                        <PostCreate />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/post/:id">
                        <PostPage />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/profile/:username">
                        <Profile />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/search">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/" exact>
                        <Feed />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
            { isLoggedIn() && <Header /> }
        </div>
      </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gadhg.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use grid layout in your App.js style, but keep in mind, every style you define in your App.js style will affect other components. In case, you want to apply style locally for each component, you can try CSS modules or styled-component as [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-best-styling-in-react-tutorial-youve-ever-seen-676f1284b945/) blog said.

Comment: i edited my question with an image example. each component have also a scss file like App.js App.scss
Header.js Header.scss